# Multiple ellipsis not working in absolute div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In my `div` is the overlay of another absolutely positioned div. However the text is still going beyond the div.

```js
var mainDiv = ".myclass";
 var mainDivP = ".myclass p";
 $(window).on("load",function(){ multiLine_ellipsis(mainDiv, mainDivP); });

 function multiLine_ellipsis(mainDiv, mainDivP) {
  $(mainDivP).each(function(index) {
    var divh = $(mainDiv).height();
    if ($(this).outerHeight() > divh) {
      var returnText = $(this).text().replace(/\W*\s(\S)*$/, '...');
      console.log(returnText);
      $(this).text(returnText);
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.myclass {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  font-family: "my-font";
  font-size: 28px;
  padding: 15px;
  height: 100px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.myOverlay {
  background-image: url("https://dksa1a9fhenpv.cloudfront.net/website/images/overlay.png");
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.outerDiv{
  width:231px;
  height:173px;
  position:relative;
}
p{margin:0 0 10px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outerDiv">
  <div class="myOverlay">
    <div class="myclass">
      <p>jadu's best Accommodation/ abcd hddndehd lfjhgs</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

I should get ... at the end of the statement but i am not getting it.

Comment: I suggest using console.log() to trace what's going on in there.

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS hides the rest, just change font-size to 30px you will see some part of the hidden part.

Comment: though my css is hiding thing but js function is such that only 3 line should be visible and then ellipsis ...

Comment: Yes, it is. To check this, you could add a `console.log(returnText)` before you use it.  And, `console.log($(this).text())` after you set it.  The trouble is caused by you set the height of `div.myclass` and set `overflow:hidden`.  So, you the "... " is hidden.

Comment: by the way, Your regular expression only match the last word `lfjhgs`.